# How to set first item as default select

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angular.js. I am using list of users with sorter list, when I click the user name the selected user phone number should display in the selected area. It is working fine.

My question is how to I set the first user as default select. here is my sample code. Please help me on this.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <h1>Selected View</h1>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="userNames in users | orderBy:orderProp:direction" ng:click="select(userNames)">{{userNames.name}}</li>
  </ul>
  <p>selected: {{selectedUser.phone}}</p>
  <script>

  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    //myApp.by.id('setbtn')element('h1').addClass('active');

    myApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.users = [{name:'John', phone:'555-1276'},
                    {name:'John', phone:'555-1278'},
                    {name:'Mary', phone:'800-BIG-MARY'},
                    {name:'Mike', phone:'555-4321'},
                    {name:'Adam', phone:'555-5678'},
                    {name:'Julie', phone:'555-8765'},
                    {name:'Juliette', phone:'555-5678'}];
    //sorting
    $scope.direction = false;
    $scope.orderProp = "name";
    $scope.sort = function(column) {
        if ($scope.orderProp === column) {
            $scope.direction = !$scope.direction;
        } else {
            $scope.orderProp = column;
            $scope.direction = false;
        }
    };
    //selected list
     $scope.select = function(phone) {
        $scope.selectedUser = phone;
     };
}]);


  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort users from controller instead of html

**HTML**

```
 <li ng-repeat="userNames in getSortedUsers()" 
       ng:click="select(userNames)">{{userNames.name}}</li>
```

**Controller**

```
 $scope.getSortedUsers = function () {
    // Use $filter service. You have to add $filter as dependencies in controller
    var users = $filter('orderBy')($scope.users, $scope.orderProp + 
                                                    ':' +  $scope.direction);

    // Set first user as selected user
    $scope.selectedUser = users[0];

    return users;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick response. It is showing the result of unsorted list value. here I am using sorting filter, so I am expecting the first first phone number after sorting. for eg (Adam phone number).

Comment: @user3621148 Apply the filter in the controller, and then select the first element.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this in the controller to sets the default user's phone number

```
$scope.selectedUser = $scope.users[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the users in a JS Object, instead of a native datatype, the initial selection often causes a problem.

You'll be better off to refactor the select options to use an array of strings rather than an array of Objects.

It is covered in detail [in this post](http://www.grobmeier.de/angular-js-ng-select-and-ng-options-21112012.html#.U3B2bq2SzMU).

Hope this helps!